# React - для чего нужны super() и super(props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, классы, redux, конструктор

пожалуйста объясните мне подробно разница между super и super(props) и в целом для чего нужен super? я прочитал в одной статье что с помощью super можно применить в конструкторе this.props, можете мне показать простой пример с использованием this.props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super()` вызывает конструктор наследуемого класса.Это необходимо когда вам нужно допустим получить доступ к переменным наследуемого класса.

В React когда вы вызываете `super` с пропсами тогда весь компонент получает доступ к ним через `this.props`.

**Без `super()`**

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 'hello'
  }
}
    
class B extends A {
  constructor(){
    console.log(this.a) //будет ошибка
  }
}
    
console.log(new B())
```

**С `super()`**

```js
class A {
  constructor(props) {
    this.props = props
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(this.props)
  }
}

console.log(new B({title: 'hello world'}))
```

Также советую прочитать  [**Why Do We write super(props)**](https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/)

Еще про ключевое слово `super` могу добавить из книги **Кайла Симпсона ES6 не только** стр. 75

Ключевое слово `super`, как правило, рассматривается в связи с классами. Но благодаря тому, что в JS понятие класса приравнивается к понятию обьекта с прототипом, ключевое слово `super` эффективно работает с краткими методами обычных обьектов.

Рассмотрим пример:

```js
var o1 = {
  foo(){
     console.log("o1.foo");
  }
}

var o2 = {
  foo(){
    super.foo();
    console.log("o2:foo");
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf( o2, o1);

o2.foo(); // o1: foo 
          // o2: foo
```

*Ключевое слово `super` допустимо только в сокращенных методах, а не в свойствах регулярных функциональных выражений. Кроме того, оно действительно только в форме super.XXX( для доступа к свойству / методу) и не применяется в форме `super()`.*